# unable to install @angular/material 8

Tags: material-design, angular8

I am using command `ng add @angular/material`

`Unable to fetch package metadata: Cannot read property 'startsWith' of null` is the error I am getting npm config list [-l] [--json];

```
cli configs metrics-registry = "https://artifacthub-tip.oraclecorp.com/api/npm/npmjs-remote" scope = "" user-agent = "npm/6.12.0 node/v12.13.0 win32 x64"; 
userconfig C:\Users\goparao\.npmrc 
http_proxy = "http://registry.npmjs.org/" 
key = "value" 
registry = "https://artifacthub-tip.oraclecorp.com/api/npm/npmjs-remote" 
strict-ssl = true; 
builtin config undefined prefix = "C:\\Users\\goparao\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm"; node bin location = C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe ; 
cwd = D:\angular_practice\hello-world ; 
HOME = C:\Users\goparao ; 

"npm config ls -l" to show all defaults.

PS D:\angular_practice\hello-world>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you still have issues to install Angular Material, you can first install it with the command : `npm i @angular/material` then run the command `ng add @angular\material`. *(Worked with Angular 10)*